# Download all files in a Documents Library and upload them to a different Share Point Installation

Tags: document-library, script

I have a SharePoint farm with several folders with documents which need to be copied to a different SharePoint installation. Is it possible to download all files with the folder structure. And re-upload them to the other SharePoint farm.

Maybe even taking over the meta data and also adding the meta data to the new installation if it is missing.

The Files are in SharePoint 2010 and  need to be moved to 2013

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Copy your SharedPoint document library URL for example, http://sumon-pc/sites/dc/ts/Shared Documents
2. Open Windows Explorer, right click My Computer and select Map Network Drive
3. Choose drive letter that you want to use, then enter the URL that you copied in step 1. Then click finish. If prompt for username and password enter your SharePoint login username and password
4. Now users can access SharePoint document library from Windows Explorer but they need to have privilege to the relevant document library that you mapped.
5. After that you can see all document in your mapped drive.
6. just copy all documents to local hard drive.
7. map the document library in which you want to upload document using above same steps & upload them.

Comment: Is it possible to move the meta data, that is added in share point like document language too?