# Editing files outside SPD

Tags: sharepoint-designer, editor

I often edit script files in /SiteAssets on the fly. I normally use SharePoint Designer for for this because I can make the edit, save, and it's applied immediately.

If I wanted to use another text editor, how could I connect to the SharePoint site and do it in real time - without having to copy it to SPD or upload it manually to the Doc Library?

Comment: Similar to what you are asking: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148195/download-all-files-in-a-documents-library-and-upload-them-to-a-different-share-p/148196#148196. After mapping it to explorer, you can just choose open as and choose another program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to map the SiteAssets folder to your local computer so you have a shortcut.

Simply open your script file as you would from your desktop.

Comment: When I go into "Map Network Drive" and paste my Site URL, it says "Windows Cannot access". I've tried every combination or URLs including the FQDN

Comment: Use the specific library, rather than the site url. I.e. 

`Document Library > open with explorer` (use internet explorer for this) 


`copy path from windows explorer > paste in map network drive dialog`

Comment: It says I need to add to Trusted Sites even though it's already in there (Local Intranet / Trusted Sites)