# Moving documents from one sharepoint location to another

Tags: document

I have a share point site which was set up and functioning as a file repository.  I have set up a new share point site and am looking to move the documents from the old site in to the new site and use metadata to tag the documents.   I am having no success in getting the documents from the old to the new location.

Answer (score 1):

The import/export spweb that Atish mentioned will indeed move the docs, but it will also move any folders and such. If you're trying to move from a folder structure to a non-folder structure, then either:

1. manual via windows explorer: open the source library with windows explorer (via the button on the ribbon), open another browser tab and navigate to the destination library,and drag and drop the files.
2. Use a 3rd party tool. They're expensive, but if you have thousands of docs in many libraries they can certainly be worth it. Tools (like sharegate) can move files from a folder structure into a flat structure, and even set metadata based on the folder they were in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using PowerShell. Export your list from old site

```
Export-SPWeb "http://www.old.com/" -itemurl "/Lists/test" -path "c:\test.cmp"
```

Now import into new site

```
Import-SPWeb "http://www.new.com/" -Path "c:\test.cmp"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy your SharedPoint document library URL for example,
   http://dev1/sites/dc/ts/Shared Documents.
2. Open Windows Explorer, right click My Computer and select Map Network Drive.
3. Choose drive letter that you want to use, then enter the URL that you copied in *step 1*. Then click finish. If prompt for username and password enter your SharePoint login username and password.
4. Now users can access SharePoint document library from Windows Explorer but they need to have privilege to the relevant document library that you mapped.
5. After that you can see all document in your mapped drive.
6. Just copy all documents to local hard drive.
7. Map the document library in which you want to upload document using above same steps & upload them.

Reference taken from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148195/download-all-files-in-a-documents-library-and-upload-them-to-a-different-share-p/148196#148196).