# Migrating files from one SharePoint to another

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, migration, document-migration

I having issues migrating files over from one SharePoint to another, I have attempted to zip and "7zip" them using the explorer view from one site and then extract them on to the other size I am hitting various errors. Document names are being shown but the files when opening them are blank.

How can i move files over without them being corrupted from one SharePoint to another?

I am using SharePoint 2010 foundation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Copy your SharedPoint document library URL for example, http://sumon-pc/sites/dc/ts/Shared Documents
> 2. Open Windows Explorer, right click My Computer and select Map Network Drive
> 3. Choose drive letter that you want to use, then enter the URL that you copied in step 1. Then click finish. If prompt for username and
>      password enter your SharePoint login username and password
> 4. Now users can access SharePoint document library from Windows Explorer but they need to have privilege to the relevant document
>      library that you mapped.
> 5. After that you can see all document in your mapped drive.
> 6. just copy all documents to local hard drive.
> 7. map the document library in which you want to upload document using above same steps & upload them.

Kindly check my answer on below post.

[Download all files in a Documents Library and upload them to a different SharePoint Installation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148195/download-all-files-in-a-documents-library-and-upload-them-to-a-different-share-p/148196#148196)

Comment: I'm receiving errors when i do this

Comment: Which step are you getting the error & Which error are you getting??

Comment: can you please provide me the error & step number so i can help you further?