# Migrating Documents from Box to SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, migration, document-migration

I need to migrate documents from [Box](http://www.box.com) to SharePoint. Is there any feasibility to do this without using the 3rd party tools? Any help on this is highly appreciated.

UPDATED: What if I download the docs from BOX and upload it to SharePoint Document library instead of migrating? what are the possible information that will get lost?

Comment: You should look this...https://community.bittitan.com/kb/Pages/Box%20to%20SharePoint%20Online%20Migration%20Guide.aspx

Comment: Did you get it or you need something else?

Comment: @Hardik thanks for the response. I am looking for a free tool to do this

Comment: If you can download the documents than you can upload them to SP online without losing anything.

Comment: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2015/09/22/step-by-step-migrate-files-to-sharepoint-online-office-365-import-service/

Answer (score 1):

If you can download the document from **BOX** to local drive than you should try below steps to **upload documents** to **SharePoint Online** Document Library

> 1. Copy your SharedPoint document library URL for example, `http://spsite.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents`
> 2. Open Windows Explorer, right click My Computer and select Map Network Drive
> 3. Choose drive letter that you want to use, then enter the URL that you copied in step 1. Then click finish. It will prompt for username
>      and password enter your SharePoint login username and password
> 4. Now users can access SharePoint document library from Windows Explorer but they need to have privilege to the relevant document
>      library that you mapped.
> 5. just copy all documents from local drive to mapped SharePoint Document library as explorer (drive).

Refer my answer below given link

[Download all files in a Documents Library and upload them to a different Share Point Installation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148195/download-all-files-in-a-documents-library-and-upload-them-to-a-different-share-p/148196#148196)

**Note:-**

I am not aware about how to download the documents from **BOX** to **local drive**.